# Dynamically set Source of the ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm trying to set country flags in a ImageView according to country name.

I follows the convention that country flag image is always stored at `drawable/flag_country_name`

for eg; drawable/flag_india, drawable/flag_south_africa

Code I written so far is

```
imageFlagRight.setImageResource(getFlagResource("India"));

private int getFlagResource(String teamName) {
        if(teamName.equals("India")){
            return R.drawable.flag_india;
        }
        if(teamName.equals("Srilanka")){
            return R.drawable.flag_srilanka;
        }
        if(teamName.equals("New Zealand")){
            return R.drawable.flag_new_zealand;
        }
        if(teamName.equals("Pakistan")){
            return R.drawable.flag_pakistan;
        }
        if(teamName.equals("Srilanka")){
            return R.drawable.flag_srilanka;
        }
        if(teamName.equals("South Africa")){
            return R.drawable.flag_south_africa;
        }
        if(teamName.equals("Austalia")){
            return R.drawable.flag_australia;
        }
        return R.drawable.flag_default;
    }
```

The above code works correctly.

Now i want to add more counties and flags. Is there any way to reduce the code lines? like 
`return R.drawable.flag+underscorise(teamName);`

Comment: imageFlagRight.setImageResource(getFlagResource("India")); In this line of code u passed india dynamically

Comment: No in real time it is like `imageFlagRight.setImageResource(getFlagResource(anObjectFromMatchList.getTeamName()));`

Comment: you have no need getFlagResource() Method, you just use below line commonly for all TeamImages imageFlagRight.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_+TeamName); where TeamName is string.Passed team name and get result

Comment: @ Ayudh you cannot simply append like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String name="flag_" + "india";
public int getFlagResource(Context context, String name) {
   int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", "com.mypackage.namehere");
   return resId;
}
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 1):

U have to Store the country name and R.id Values....

When u want get those Values And display it

Answer (score 1):

With the input from @Saurabh Pareek

```
private int getFlagResource(String teamName) {
         String flagString = "flag_"+teamName.replace(" ", "_").toLowerCase();
         int resId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(flagString, "drawable", "com.mypackage.namehere");
         if(resId != 0){
             return resId;
         }
         return R.drawable.flag_default;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<yourimageview>.setImageViewResource(getFlagResource("india"));
```